# How to cache only when the json is valid

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, guava

I have a spring rest api application that is using HATEOAS/PagingAndSortingRepository to do most of the heavy lifting.

I have implemented caching using guava but I am having issues where when the user cancels the request midway through an api call, it caches the incomplete json and re-serves it for 60 seconds.

I am trying to use the `unless=""` parameter of the `@Cacheable` annotation. Previously, I just used `unless="#result == null"` but that does not handle incomplete or invalid json.

This does not seem to work either. So now I am trying to use `com.google.gson.JsonParser` to parse the result and invalidate if applicable.

Repository

```
    @RepositoryRestResource(path = "products", collectionResourceRel = "products")
    public interface ProductEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ProductEntity, String> {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(); 

        @Cacheable(value = CacheConfig.STORE_CACHE)
        ProductEntity findByName(String name); 
    }
```

Cache Config

```
    public final static String PRODUCTS_CACHE = "products";

    @Bean
    public Cache productsCache() {
        return new GuavaCache(PRODUCTS_CACHE, CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build());
    }
```

How do I detect invalid json in the `unless=""` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own issue!

When I interrupted the api request to `localhost/products` and re-requested, I finally saw an error about not being able to fetch a onetomany mapping. I believe the error was `lazy initialization error for a collection`.

I solved this issue by adding `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` to my models where the `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` mappings were decalared.

For example:

```
    @Entity(name = "product")
    @Table(name = "products", schema = "${DB_NAME}", catalog = "")
    public class ProductEntity {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private List shipments = new ArrayList<>();

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 10)
        public String getName() {  return name;  } 
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shipmentID", targetEntity=ShipmentEntity.class)
        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
        public Collection<ShipmentEntity> getShipments() { return shipments; }
        public void setShipments(Collection<ShipmentEntity> shipments) { this.shipments = shipments; }


    }
```